# rsuite table render dynamic column and row

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, rsuite

I would like to render table columns and rows in rsuite table dynamically according to the data passed without hardcoding the column and data.

import { Table, Column, HeaderCell, Cell, RowDataType } from 'rsuite-table';
import  'rsuite-table/dist/css/rsuite-table.css'

import React from 'react'

export default function App() {

```
// Sample table data
const sampleData : any[] = [
    { firstName: 'Gourav', lastName: 'Hammad', city: 'Mhow' },
    { firstName: 'Rithik', lastName: 'Verma', city: 'Indore' },
    { firstName: 'Kartik', lastName: 'Malik', city: 'Raipur' },
    { firstName: 'Nikhil', lastName: 'Kapoor', city: 'Rau' },
    { firstName: 'Ayush', lastName: 'Singh', city: 'Dewas' }
]

return (
    <div style={{
        display: 'block', width: 700, paddingLeft: 30
    }}>
        <h4>React Suite Table Component</h4>
 
        <Table
            height={500}
            data={sampleData}
        >    
    here I want to generate the column and row based on given data 
        </Table>
    </div>
);
```

}

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const sampleData = [{}, {}, {}] // some array of objects
const keys = Object.keys(sampleData[0]);

return (
    <div style={{
        display: 'block', width: 700, paddingLeft: 30
    }}>
        <h4>React Suite Table Component</h4>
 
        <Table
            height={500}
            data={sampleData}
        >    
     /// here I want to generate the column and row based on given data 
          {
            keys.map(data_key => (
               <Column>
                   <HeaderCell>{data_key}</HeaderCell>
                   <Cell dataKey={data_key} />
               </Column>
            ))
          }
        </Table>
    </div>
);
```

dont forget take care off key because using map